# Create new directory like explorer menu

Tags: c#, api, winapi, treeview

My c# (winForm) app contain dataTree view with context Menu strip, 
i want to add Menu strip Item at name : New Directory , that when it click i create a new directory on my treeview.
The problem is i want to create the dirctory like it done in windows , right-click -->new -> folder. (i want dir appear and i choose her name exactly like win)..

i think this need to do by win API , by i did not to do this/

Thank!

Answer (score 3):

How's this:

```
public void CreateNewFolder()
{
   var newNode = myTreeView.Nodes.Add("New Folder");
   newNode.BeginEdit();
}
```

That add's a new node to the list, and then puts it into label edit mode.

Comment: Only need to add : myTreeView.LabelEdit = true;